# Deserializing just a single node of a JSON response

Tags: c#, .net, json, dictionary, json.net

I have a json response like

```
{
  "appStatus":{
    "status":true
  },
  "lastSyncDate":"06-07-2013 13.54.27",
  "configResponse":{
    "status":{
      "status":true
    },
    "configs":{
      "APPLOGENABLED":{
        "configCode":"APPLOGENABLED",
        "configDesc":"enable or disable logging from front end",
        "configType":"TAB",
        "configValue":"Y"
      },
      "COMMENTSTIMER":{
        "configCode":"COMMENTSTIMER",
        "configDesc":"timer for comments in seconds",
        "configType":"TAB",
        "configValue":"60"
      },
      "SUMMARYTIMER":{
        "configCode":"SUMMARYTIMER",
        "configDesc":"timer for summary in seconds",
        "configType":"TAB",
        "configValue":"30"
      },
      "ALERTSTIMER":{
        "configCode":"ALERTSTIMER",
        "configDesc":"timer for alerts in seconds",
        "configType":"TAB",
        "configValue":"60"
      }
    },
    "lastSyncDate":"06/07/2013 13.48.13"
  }
}
```

Using json.NET, I want to extract `configResponse` into dictionary.  I know i can directly convert a Dictionary object like this

```
  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>()....
```

but since `configResponse` is a sub element, I am not able to parse it as required.

I want to deserialize the above json response as

```
public class ConfigResponse
{
    public Status status { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, ConfigurationItem> configs { get; set; }
    public string lastSyncDate { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigurationItem
{
    public String configCode { get; set; }
    public String configDesc { get; set; }
    public String configType { get; set; }
    public String configValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you add your complete code for better understanding

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have only use this method and it worked.

```
 await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<ConfigResponse>(jsontoobject, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not even solve your own question. Plus you don't mention what `jsontoobject` even is. The other answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 5):

You can parse JSON string into `JObject`, get sub-object "configResponse", then deserialize it into `ConfigResponse`. It's one line of code:

```
JObject.Parse("{...}")["configResponse"].ToObject<ConfigResponse>()
```

If you need a custom serializer to set deserialization options, you can pass it to `ToObject<T>()` method.